# ¿Que diferencia hay entre declarar un objeto JSON con : y =?

Tags: javascript, json, variables

Siempre he tenido la duda de que diferencia hay entre el `obj1` y `obj2`

```
var obj1 = {
  propiedad1: String,
  propiedad2: Boolean,
  propiedad3: Number,
  propiedad4: null,
  propiedad5: "Opcion1" || "Opcion2",
  propiedad6: {
     propiedad1: String,
     propiedad2: Boolean,
  }
}
var obj2 : {
  propiedad1: String,
  propiedad2: Boolean,
  propiedad3: Number,
  propiedad4: null,
  propiedad5: "Opcion1" | "Opcion2",
  propiedad6: {
     propiedad1: String,
     propiedad2: Boolean,
  }
}
```

¿ Cuando se usa los `:` y cuando el `=` ?

Comment: JSON y objeto Javascript son dos cosas distintas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/164943/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-json-y-un-objeto-en-javascript/164944#164944

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El operador `=` es para **asignación en el lenguaje** mientras que `:` es para **definición en la notación**.
Me explico:

Javascript es un lenguaje de programación y

> Cuando creas un objeto en el código de programación, los valores **pueden** cambiar en cualquier momento durante la ejecución. Para hacerlo, simplemente creas variables y les asignas valores mediante el uso de `=`. Ejemplo: `var x = 2;`

Por otro lado, JSON es [solo una notación para intercambio de información entre diferentes lenguajes y plataformas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) y

> Cuando creas un objeto en notación Json, los valores **no** van a cambiar una vez asignados, por lo tanto los estás *definiendo*. Esto únicamente es válido en una cadena JSON ya que [así está definido](http://json.org/).

Comment: puedes agregar un ejemplo declarando la variable el tipo y su valor e imprimirlo por consola; seria bueno para completar tu respuesta!  , agregando un string a un integer

Comment: es que lo que quiero es definir el tipo de datos que va a tener una propiedad en mi objeto, creare otra pregunta

Comment: un tipo de datos tambien puede ser una objeto es decir si defines una clase con caracteristicas puedes hacer un new object[]

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111643/como-definir-un-arreglo-de-un-tipo-de-datos-en-una-propiedad-en-un-objeto-json esta es la pregunta