# ¿Como definir un arreglo de un tipo de datos en una propiedad en un objeto JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

tengo esl siguente obj

```
nuevoEvento : {
    infoBasica : {
        nombre: String,
        escenario:String,
        valor: [{
            titulo: String,
            valor: String
        }],
        lugar:{
            escenario: String,  
            direccion: String,
            barrio: String,
            ciudad: String,
        },
        genero: String,
        modalidad: String,
        edad: [{
            titulo: String,
            rango: String
        }],
        fechas:{
            inicio: {
                fecha: Date,
                hora: TimeRanges
            },
            limite: {
                fecha: Date,
                hora: TimeRanges
            }
        },
        tipoCompetencia: "Individual" | "Equipos",
    },
    infoAvanzada : {
        cupos: Number,
        inscriptos: String,
        premios: Array<Premio>

    }
}
```

Mi inquietud es mas exactamente en la propiedad premio, quiero que solo me reciba un arraglo de datos de tipo Premio

```
export class Premio {
    titulo: String
    valor: String
    constructor(titulo, valor) {
        this.titulo = titulo
        this.valor = valor
    }
}
```

¿Eso estaría correcto?

Comment: te da error? seria algo asi premios = new Premio[]

Comment: tambien me da error infoAvanzada : {
   cupos: Number,
   inscriptos: String,
   premios: new Premio[]
   
  }

Comment: iba a escribir la respuesta pero ya la dieron; de igual forma usando typescript la opcion que te di es valida

Comment: prueba sin el new

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que sea un arreglo del tipo `Premio`, deberías ponerlo:

```
premios: [Premio]
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no puedes definir tipos en Javascript, o al menos no desde el enfoque que necesitas. En casos como estos, la opción adecuada, si quieres seguir usando la sintaxis de Javascript, es programar en TypeScript.

Comment: si, estoy usando el framework de Ionic2